# SEARCH API + VIEW to search members

Tags: search

I have a website in Drupal version 7.28. I have page where i want to search members by using Search option created from VIEW. It goes like this after submission:

https://domain.com/search-members?search_api_views_fulltext=anything

This page and functionalty was working fine few days back but not now. Page is blank without any error. There is result in database.

I can understand above info might not be sufficient to help but my only question is:

What can cause a blank page without an error? Possible problems?

Here is the updated ERROR MSG:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aeeee01_drpl21.search_api_db_user_index_field_business_phone' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM (SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_business_phone} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_0) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_city} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_1) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_country} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_2) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_department} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_3) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_first_name_} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_4) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_job_institution} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_5) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_job_title} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_6) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_last_name} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_7) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_member_advisor} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_8) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_specialization} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_9) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_state} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_10) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_field_zip_code} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_11) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM {search_api_db_user_index_name} t WHERE (word = :db_condition_placeholder_12) ) t GROUP BY t.item_id) subquery; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_7] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_8] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_9] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_10] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_11] => mlang [:db_condition_placeholder_12] => mlang ) in SearchApiDbService->search() (line 928 of /home1/aeeee01/public_html/sites/all/modules/search_api_db/service.inc).

Comment: may be your are not displaying anything on your tpl file(template) or your template missing..

Comment: Did you check what the database log says and your apache log?

Comment: Hi, Pontus and Gobinath 

i'm displaying code because it was working few days back.

and i did check apache log but i'm not sure if i'm checking it correctly as on server log folder is Blank and log file on root is showing logs related to old dates. nothing is related to it. any other reason? I'll update you soon this comment if i get anything for Database log.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the error msg. Could please give  it a one shot if possible?

Comment: Did you change anything in the taxonomy of the users? Like delete one taxonomy field, or change vocabulary or terms tid/name? It looks like your search is looking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this : 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7#comment-7019

https://api.drupal.org/comment/51338#comment-51338

https://api.drupal.org/comment/16974#comment-16974

And check if you made change in your taxonomy vocabulary, deleting any fields that the search would index in the views.

You can also re-index your user.

Comment: After looking deeply into database i found mentioned line in ERROR: 
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aeeee01_drpl21.search_api_db_user_index_field_business_phone' doesn't exist:

It is pointing to a table which has a little different name.  

It says: search_api_db_user_index_field_business_phon
But in DB it is: search_api_db_user_index_1_field_business_phone


Could u plz confirm how it could b changed n can i solve it frm backend setting by doing any UNDO or RESET or something?

Database is very huge i cant do quick solution as there are too many tables with "_1_"

Please suggest.

Comment: Well, I can't say for sure it is about taxonomy, but it is one of the few very steps you should check. I had once a placeholder crash and it was about taxonomy. I would say, first start with the easiest, re-index your users (admin/config/search/search_api/index/your_user_index clear all indexed data, then index it again). Then second more easy, check if some of the data values of your tables are with `"` or `'`

Comment: And if you do this, make a test of your search at every batch of indexation

Comment: ok I just see what you said about the machine name. Re-indexing could work, you can check in your user_index the fields indexed and see if you can change them to the right field_business_phone. You might have 2 of this kind or have deleted one, changed one.

Comment: Thank you so much Tritof for your kind help. I'm on it. Will update this thread once i see any solution or issue. Indexing is running for site.

I am/was just confused, if in error it is saying table is missing and in database table exists with slightly different name then can the solution be Indexing for this issue?
You may leave your reply if you get time though i'm already following your instructions. Lets hope it will do the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: can you provide infos on your setup: so you have search api, seach database, and likely a user index for the search. Am I correct? If it is the case, you might be able to choose which fields are indexed by the search database. As an example, in one site I am working on with user, it is here: admin/config/search/search_api/index/user_index/fields. From there I can decide which fields are indexed. If I want to change one of them, I would do it there and then re-index the users. the error message suggest that you had a first field_business_phon and then a second field_business_phone.

Comment: So the search system is looking into field_business_phon and loose its way because it might have been deleted or changed. I see 2 other ways maybe: 1/change the machine-name of the field_business_phone, deleting the last 'e', but I am not sure it is a good idea as it can create other unexpected error. 2/ see if in the search views you can edit the fields search. You can use for example search:combine in the filters and choose the fields. I hope this helps. Keep me posted, tmw I'll check if you found.

Comment: Hi Tritof,

I tried to run CRON job manually also but unable to RE-INDEX user.
In your last msg you pointed to a field "Phone" & "Phon". It was a TYPO i apologies. Please refer to my first msg in this post for correct error detail.

And yes u r right i have Search API, Search Database and User index. and all main fields are checked to search.

Still page is blank. Important thing indexing is not site successful. I'm trying.

Comment: in your error message there is `line 928 of /home1/aeeee01/public_html/sites/all/modules/search_api_db/service.inc`. I looked in the file and I found line 926-928 `watchdog('search_api_db', 'An overlong word (more than 50 characters) was encountered while indexing, due to bad tokenizing. ' .'Please check your settings for the "Tokenizer" preprocessor to ensure that data is tokenized correctly.',array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);`. Then looking for `SQLSTATE[42S02]`on the internet shows a lot of time mispelling and case sensitive issues. It may be something related to a upper/lower case, too long word

Comment: Maybe check your values for the fields, especially the taxonomy one if there are: 1/ upper-lower case, 2/ special characters like " or ', 3/ taxonomy machine name incorrect (all machine-name should be lower case and alphanum.). It looks like something put the system down. Did you find anything special in the watchdog or the log messages if still activated in the interface?

Comment: What you can do is unchecked all the fields in your user index, try re-indexing, then check one field, try re-index, and so on, until it become impossible to re-index. You would know which field(s) can be a problem

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right question to ask . but is there any option i can seek for Chat with you? because this might save time. Its ok if you find this inappropriate. Please suggest.

Comment: You can chat only if you have 20 as reputation I think, sorry. Anyway, it is not inappropriate, but I would say you I can't do that, I am working and I can just take a look sometimes when I am having a break.

Comment: Gmail chat? if possible? or any other msngr option?

Comment: sorry, can't I am working in the same time and need to stay mainly focus on my project's issues right now. I think by unchecking the fields and re-indexing step by step with every field, you might find the field who is an issue, then check mispelling, case sensitivity, and machine names, you might find the one(s) bugging your search system

Comment: I understand it completely. My bad..! 

1) http://snag.gy/7ohiO.jpg
2) http://snag.gy/0cEt0.jpg
3) http://snag.gy/qbt6h.jpg

here i can see there are 2 User Index.

User index and User index 2.

Member page is integrated with User index but in database it seems table are created through User Index 2  .. can i change it to User index 2 in backend?

Comment: maybe... it would be probably more simple to have only one user index. You can disable one and the other and see what happens

Comment: yes, I tried by disabling USER INDEX but site broken as a result.
if i disable USER INDEX 2 it did nothing.

Member page is with USER INDEX but i want it with USER INDEX2 where i can change it? any suggestion?

Comment: maybe use "Global: Combine fields filter" instead of full text search, so you can choose the fields of search and combine them. It works pretty well, I use it

Comment: :| Still couldn't get it working.

Comment: also when i run indexing it says: An error occurred during indexing: Could not index items since important pending server tasks. anyway to see all pending cron tasks? and delete it?

Comment: you should truncate the caches in the db, reduce the number of tasks of the cron batch, and look into the watchdog, there should be something about interesting when the problems started

Comment: I followed above instructions and reduced the number of tasks to 10 . it is still same. 
 An error occurred during indexing: Could not index items since important pending server tasks.

Comment: You should really take this discussion to chat.

Answer (score 0):

When there is an error Drupal will often show a [WSOD](https://drupal.org/node/158043) (white screen of death), so it hides the error for security reasons.

I would recommend to rebuild the index or delete and remake the index. Also check in the fields tab of search api if all needed fields to index are checked.

If you change any fields you should always reindex.